# How to write a job in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have had very minimal experience in writing jobs. A long time ago, I had written a very small simple java job for reading and writing files using `tasklet` in java. Now I have to learn how to write jobs in `Perl`.

Normally, in such cases, I google out the information, but I am not getting any information on how to write jobs in perl in internet searches. Can anyone please let me know of any internet resources or books, which I can download from the internet for learning perl jobs.

I have a little knowledge in Perl.

Comment: What does "write a job" mean? What is a "Perl job" and how does it differ from a standard Perl script? Are you talking about a cron job?

Comment: @ChrisDown What i mean is , normally from my experience, when i wrote jobs in java , they used to be scheduled by a scheduler. My guess is , in case of Perl it will be the same, if it is not chron , then it will be something other than it like: IBM scheduler etc. But where i am confused is just what you  asked. What is a Perl job and is there any difference  between it and a standard Perl script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the script, using the proper syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
<your code>
```

Put the file somewhere.
Make the script executable (chmod a+x yourscript.pl).
Then run the script using *cron* (with *crontab*, or writing a file in /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.hourly, etc, depending on your needs).
Depending on your choice of *cron*, the call to the script varies.

Comment: For beginners (and not only for them) it usually is a good idea to put `use strict;` right on the second line before any actual code.

Comment: Thanks, so a perl job is but a perl script run using a scheduler. Thanks for the info. @peterph: Thanks for the advice, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 5):

First make sure what Perl is good for and what not so much. As usual, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)  gives you a good overview - you should also be able to get some idea about what Chris Down meant when he asked you: *'What is a "Perl job" and how does it differ from a standard Perl script? Are you talking about a cron job?'*

Then continue with some Perl tutorials. The [Perl homepage](http://www.perl.org/) is a rather obvious starting point, but you will also probably be interested in:

- [Perl learning portal](http://www.perl.org/learn.html)
- [freely available books on Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/library.html)
- [Perl Programming at Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful info. Sure i will have a look into those, though i am already aware of them and i have actually used  little bit of perl long ago. But i was perplexed when i saw the moniker `job`   associated with perl scripting. Now it's clear that they are one and the same. Up voted for the explanation and the internet resources.